# Please review these code. It doesn't work like I expected

Tags: java

The code didn't work as I think.I have tried to recode but still can't get the result I hope for. Here's the code:

```
public class Node<T> {

    private List<Node<T>> children = new ArrayList<Node<T>>();
    private Node<T> parent = null;
    private T data = null;
    private String a = "";

    public Node(T data) { //used to create parent
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Node(T data, Node<T> parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
        Node<T> child = new Node<T>(data);
        this.parent.children.add(child); 
    }

    public Node<T> getParent(Node<T> child){
        return child.parent;
    }

    public List<Node<T>> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public int getSize(){
        return children.size();
    }

    public String toString(){
        for(int i=0; i<children.size();i++){
          a = a + parent.children.get(i).getData()+ ",";
        }
        return a ;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }
}



import java.util.List;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node<String> parentNode = new Node<String>("Parent");
        Node<String> childNode1 = new Node<String>("Child 1", parentNode);
        Node<String> childNode2 = new Node<String>("Child 2", parentNode);
        List<Node<String>> ChildrenOfParents = parentNode.getChildren();
        System.out.println(ChildrenOfParents.size());
        System.out.println(ChildrenOfParents.toString());


    }

}
```

After these lines of code, I wonder why ChildrenOfParents.toString() will not print out the children? Those child already added into the ChildrenOfParents right? I'm still new in java. Please guide me through the code. I wish to make a family tree without restriction of Family members(For example, father can have many sons instead of just 2 if follow binary tree). Thanks.

PS: Thanks for the answer that "this.parent.children.add(this)" makes the program works. But I wonder why "this.parent.children.add(child)" at line 12 doesn't work when the constructor with parameter is called? Isn't the parent's children variable will add the child into the list?

Comment: please, check the format of your post. And your ChildrenOfParents.size() should be zero. You add nothing to it.

Comment: You are not adding any item to the list.

Comment: Terrible title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: Sorry. I am still new to both StackOverflow and java. My apologize for all bad things i have made just now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add child into parent object in the second constructor:
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

```
public class Node<T> {

    private List<Node<T>> children = new ArrayList<Node<T>>();
    private Node<T> parent = null;
    private T data = null;

    public Node(T data) { //used to create parent
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Node(T data, Node<T> parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.data = data;
        this.parent.children.add(this);
    }

    public Node<T> getParent(Node<T> child) {
        return child.parent;
    }

    public List<Node<T>> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return children.size();
    }

    public String toString() {
        String a = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
            a = a + children.get(i).getData() + ",";
        }
        return a;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }
}

public class NodeApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node<String> parentNode = new Node<String>("Parent");
        Node<String> childNode1 = new Node<String>("Child 1", parentNode);
        Node<String> childNode2 = new Node<String>("Child 2", parentNode);
        System.out.println(parentNode.getSize());
        System.out.println(parentNode.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have done some editing, but I still can't print out those Children. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Please see implementation https://github.com/sbzDev/stackoverflow/tree/master/question56014777